# Animated Dropdown with saperate cells animation in android

Tags: android, animation, drop-down-menu, android-animation

I need a **drop-down** with *animation* to open/close like this.
It needs **animation with cells**. You can see that in below *animation image*.

[image]

If anyone has an *idea* or a *tutorial* related to this *solution* than please **share it with me**.
Thanks in advance.
If you have any **questions** or **querys** in your mind than *feel free to ask me*.
I really want to get the *proper solution* to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom expand and collapse animations to show and hide a view. On top view clicked, expand and collapse required view. For this, you have to first calculate height of view.
Expand and collapse animation functions are followings.

Expand

```
/**
     * Expanding a view with animation based on its height
     */
    public static void expand(final View v,final int targetHeight) {
        v.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation a = new Animation()
        {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                        ? targetHeight
                        : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // 1dp/ms
        a.setDuration((int)(targetHeight*2 / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        v.startAnimation(a);
    }
```

Collapse

```
/**
 * Collapsing a view with animation based on its height
 */
public static void collapse(final View v,final int initialHeight)
{

    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if(interpolatedTime == 1){
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int)(initialHeight*2 / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

Comment: Moreover, you can use expandable listview following this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for your answer @atifali. I'll try it and let you know about result.